# Distribution function related with the limit from left

Tags: real-analysis, probability, measure-theory

show that the distribution fun $F$ of random variable $f$ takes only values $0$ and $1$ iff there exists areal number $c$ such that $P(f=c)=1$ ??

I begin solve the ex and i prove $F$ takes two value $0$ and $1$ (one side )

another side I had  problem

suppose $F$ takes two values $0$ and $1$ ,
 we must found $c$ satisfies $P(f=c)=1$

but I know $P(f=c)=P(f\leq c)-P(f<c)$

and I know $P(f<c)=\lim F(x)$ as $x$ approached to $c$ from left

Comment: See https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1657609/if-the-cdf-of-x-is-i-a-infty-then-px-a-1

Answer (score 1):

Hint:

Define $c:=\inf\{x\in \mathbb R\mid F(x)=1\}$

Then, since $F$ is continuous from the right, we have $F(c)=1$.

What can be said about $F(x)$ if $x<c$?

What does that say about $P(f=c)$?

Comment: F(x) =0 if x<c . if we use the def of lim F(x)=1  as x approach to @\infty$ i show this hint but cant conncted this with problem !!

Comment: No. $F(x)=1$ implies that $c\leq x$ by the definion of $c$ as infimum. So $F(x)\neq1$ if $x<c$ and since there are only two possible values for $F(x)$ we find that $F(x)=0$ for $x<c$.